# Remove value from array by value or key in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array with structure as following

```
 #items: array:2 [
    8 => 46
    46 => 7
  ]
```

i want to remove the value 46 from the array in order to get an array like this

```
 #items: array:2 [
    8,7
  ]
```

this is my try

```
        $ary = Auth::user()->friends()->pluck('user_id')->toArray();

        $value_to_remove = Auth::id();
        $output = [];

        $output[] = array_search($value_to_remove, $ary);
        $output[] = $ary[$value_to_remove];
```

error message : {message: "Undefined offset: 46", exception: "ErrorException",…}

Comment: What happens if you have an element where neither value is to be removed? E.g `47=>4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
<?php

$ary = [
    8 => 46,
    46 => 7
];

$value_to_remove = 46;
$output = [];

$output[] = array_search($value_to_remove, $ary);
$output[] = $ary[$value_to_remove];

print_r($output);
```

Comment: dosen't work message: "Trying to access array offset on value of type int"

Comment: @markvazquez why doesn't it work? is there any error message, is the output wrong, maybe the input array is different?